# Counter Strike Source

Tags: wine, steam

I get installation error for Counter Strike source with wine:
I entered the following command in terminal:

```
wine Counter Strike Source.exe
```

Below is my progress.

```
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/monojit/.wine'
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x103e368, overlapped 0x103e380): stub
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x10fe8a0, overlapped 0x10fe8ac): stub
wine: configuration in '/home/monojit/.wine' has been updated.
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\Counter.exe"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why Wine? There is a Linux version supporting Ubuntu natively. This always is preferable, if only to support game development for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Space characters are used as delimiter characters between separate words in bash. You got the error `wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\Counter.exe"` because each space character in file name needs to be escaped by a preceding backslash character `\` or else the file name that contains blank spaces must be enclosed in quote characters in order for it to be parsed as a single file name.

Change directories using the `cd` command to the directory that contains the *Counter Strike Source.exe* file so that *Counter Strike Source.exe* can be run by wine without needing to type the full path to it. Enclose the string `Counter Strike Source.exe` in a pair of quote characters so that it will be evaluated as a single word instead of three separate words like this:

```
wine 'Counter Strike Source.exe'
```

Comment: this answer helped me, I removed spaces in the file name and it worked lol

Answer (score 0):

To remove the error on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS:

```
02ae:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
```

This did the trick for me:

```
sudo apt-get install winebind
```